# check/uncheck checkboxs

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do this for an hour, I tried various of examples but all react the same:

```
$('body').append('<div id="allchecks">checkBoxes:<br />');
$('#allchecks').append('<input id="mcheck" type="checkbox"/>mainCheck<hr />');

for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    $('#allchecks').append('<input class="regCheck" type="checkbox" />regularCheck<br />');
}
$('#allchecks').append('</div>');

$('#mcheck').click(function () {
    if ($('#mcheck').is(':checked')) {
        $('.regCheck').attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        $('.regCheck').removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
```

The first 2 tries works but after the second try nothing work.
If I look at the source after 2 tries the ' attr('checked', 'checked') ' appears 
and ' removeAttr('checked') ' occur also.

But not visual.

Can someone please explain why is it happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) with a boolean:

```
$('#mcheck').click(function () {
    if ($('#mcheck').is(':checked')) {
        $('.regCheck').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('.regCheck').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

---

Here's a much shorter version of the same thing:

```
$('#mcheck').click(function () {
    $('.regCheck').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

---

**P.S.** Please learn to [cache your elements](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/06/19/speed-up-the-jquery-code-selectors-cache/), instead of constantly traversing the DOM. Also, you probably want to use the `change` event, not `click`.

Comment: Thanks it worked:) i used the prop but not with a Boolean, 'prop' is the current value of 'checked' while 'attr' is the default one right? but why only Boolean with 'prop'? I tried it with 'checked' and it worked for the first two times why did it happen, can you please explain?

Comment: @slash1z - Any string is truthy, so `prop('checked', 'checked')` is equivalent to `.prop('checked', true)`. For clarity, please stick to the Boolean.

Comment: Good answer, what about `$('#allchecks').append('</div>');`? OP is misusing `append` method.

Comment: Oh sorry i think i got it wrong, isn't the div close only after the last element (after the for loop)?

Comment: I don't understand something, if I delete `$('body').append('</div>')` that `div` is still get closed, how come?

Comment: @slash1z Actually browser closes the tag here `$('body').append('<div id="allchecks">checkBoxes:<br />');` not  `$('body').append('</div>')`.

Comment: @ undefined, OK thanks. So it's right to not close it directly and let the browser close it for me?

Comment: Can someone please explain, How come in the first two attempts my initial code worked?